# May any one please help me: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): ,

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, system.data.sqlite

Please solve my problem:
This is the code line

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Overhead_Table where IDNO="+incomingrecord[0]+" AND DATE_TIME LIKE "+DTTIME+"%" ,null);
```

I Also tried:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Overhead_Table where IDNO=? AND DATE_TIME LIKE ?%" ,new String[] {incomingrecord[0],DTTIME});
```

and

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Overhead_Table where IDNO=? AND DATE_TIME LIKE ?" ,new String[] {incomingrecord[0],DTTIME+"%"});
```

But it shows error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code
> 1): , while compiling: select * from Overhead_Table where
> IDNO=6765456765 AND DATE_TIME LIKE 14,01,2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use `?` placeholders:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Overhead_Table WHERE IDNO = ? AND DATE_TIME LIKE ? || '%'";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql , new String[] {incomingrecord[0], DTTIME});
```

I assume that both `incomingrecord[0]` and `DTTIME` are strings.

Comment: Thanks Dear But how can I implement like matching case from left of DTTIME fields.

Comment: @AijazAli this is what `DATE_TIME LIKE ? || '%'` does.

Comment: Ok Thank you dear it is great to talk you.

Comment: Thank you dear it is great to see your help

Comment: Love you jani you solved my issue it works. Thank you.